# Not able to capture images when there is an incoming call?

Tags: android

I am continuously capturing images with my camera at interval of 1 min.It is working without any problem.But when i got incoming call,my camera activity goes to background and not capturing any images.When call finishes m able to see my activity and images are captured without any problem.

What to do so that when incoming call,still camera should capture images.

Thanks and Regards.

Rohan Wagh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What to do so that when incoming call,still camera should capture images.

If the problem occurs if your "camera activity goes to background" for other reasons (e.g., open a Notification that leads to some other activity, press the HOME button), then I think you are out of luck. The camera preview is required to capture images, and the preview is not visible while other activities have the foreground (e.g., in-call screen).

If the problem is specific to the in-call screen, though, that I cannot explain.

Comment: @ CommonsWare - but i am not taking pictures manually..pictures are captured automatically by camera.Whether u want to say that "If by any chance camera preview goes to background(Home Key Press,Call key press,Incoming call) then camera will not take any picture? We can't do anything so that camera will take pictures even if camera preview is not visible?"

Comment: @Waugh: "We can't do anything so that camera will take pictures even if camera preview is not visible?" -- I know that you need a camera preview to exist to take pictures. I have not experimented with what happens if the preview exists but is not in the foreground. This is why I suggested you try another means of moving your activity to the background, such as pressing the HOME key. If the problem persists, then the limitation is probably that the camera preview must be visible, and I doubt there is anything to be done about that.

Comment: @ CommonsWare - Thanks a lot for your valuable reply in quick time.I think whatever i m trying to achieve is may be limitation..Please reply back to me if u got any way out.